# plot two lines on the same axes without leading to overlapping values on the y axis

Tags: r, plot, label, graphing, trendline

Is there a way to change the y axis in R so that there isn't overlapping numbers when you plot two trend lines ?
I have managed to plot the two lines I am considering in one graph but there is a nasty Y axis - does anyone know how to avoid this happening?

[image: 1]

Comment: Use `lines()` instead of `plot()` the second time and delete the `par(new = TRUE)`.

Comment: If you need more help than that, please share a tiny bit of sample data to illustrate the problem, and also please share your code as text rather than image.